# Set ALL cpu cores to PERFORMANCE permanently

Tags: linux, performance, cpu

There seems to have been some (stupid) change to the Linux kernel, where the CPU are stymied to a low power setting.

running cpufreq-info I get:
`The governor "ondemand" may decide which speed to use`

I see that I can change one core like this:
`sudo cpufreq-set -c95 -g performance`

But how do I set ALL cpu cores to PERFORMANCE permanently (persist across reboots)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vi /etc/default/cpufrequtils

make like this:
`GOVERNOR="performance"`

then:

```
sudo systemctl restart cpufrequtils
```

check with this:

```
cpufreq-info
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it'll work on x86 computers, but it does work on the RaspberryPi:

```bsh
echo performance | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
```